# Objects from DB entities

Tags: c#, object

Ok, new to Objects and have been doing a lot of reading as of late (thanks to a few recommendations from users on this site).  I've got a program (much like many programs) which modifies DB tables.  I'm just going to use 1 piece as an example here but we have the need to store and modify "Files" and those "Files" will have a "FileType".  So for a single instance of a File, I created an Object like so:

```
public class File
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FileDescription { get; set; }
    public FileType ???
}
```

And another one called FileType:

```
public class FileType
{
   public string FileTypeName { get; set; }
   public string FileTypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

So in the program, a user can save a file.  The program would create a new instance of object "File" and fill in the properties with the user data.  Each instance of a "File" must have a FileType (Photo, Email, etc.).  So how can I use my "FileType" to ensure the right "types" of files are being added to the "File" object?  I thought about using File as the Base object but then what happens if I have more than 1 property that needs to reference a type of some sort?  I can't inherit from more than 1 class, so that wouldn't work.

Sorry if it's confusing but my DB tables are pretty simple:

```
    Files
     --FileID
     --FileTypeID
     --FileName
     --FilePath
     --FileSize
     --FileDescription

    FileTypes
     --FileTypeID
     --FileType
     --FileTypeDescription
```

And these tables are 1 to many on FileTypeID.

Comment: I don't understand this: "I thought about using File as the Base object but then what happens if I have more than 1 property that needs to reference a type of some sort?" What's wrong with having File as the base class, and having each subclass set the type?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but I guess it's my lack of knowledge in this subject that maybe doing that.  I guess because File depends on FileType then the FileType can be added as a subclass to File, is that what you are saying?  What if a user wants to enter/modify FileType information, then they can access it through the File class?  I think I understand it if that's what you are talking about....